# Why are my divs not animating on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, masonry

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/IekLw

I'm trying to replicate the tympanus demo using masonry and animonscroll.js.  the only difference is I'm using div cards with images inside them instead of just images.

Here is the working tympanus demo http://jsfiddle.net/Sfmv9/19/light/

And here is my code: http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/eghEm

You can see I have masonry working, but the anim on scroll effect is not working.  I've actually been trying to figure this out for a few weeks, and just can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Here is my javascript, the rest of the code is in my codepen link.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.container').imagesLoaded(function() {
      $('.container').masonry({
       itemSelector: '.grid_4',
       isFitWidth: true,
       gutter: 8
      });

      });

    new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( '.grid_4' ), {
            minDuration : 0.4,
            maxDuration : 0.7,
            viewportFactor : 0.2
          } );

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a forked codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CotJv

It looks like you have a few issues with your codepen.

1) Your codepen is incomplete. Unlike the jsfiddle you linked to, the codepen does not have all the resources. If you add animOnScroll and the `animate` CSS (I copied just one from the working fiddle, you may desire another animation), etc. you don't have an error thrown immediately.

2) The `animOnScroll.js` file referenced on the jsfiddle page handles the imagesLoaded and masonry init internally. If you're going to use that file, I'd recommend allowing animOnScroll.js to continue handling those.

3) The `animOnScroll.js` file expects a certain DOM tree. Specifically, it wants to see unordered lists (`ul` and `li`). If you don't mind hosting the file, you can make the change directly to the file and change those requirements.

All that together, here's a forked codepen that illustrates those changes:

Again, codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CotJv

I keep your markup, but update the JS to work with it. The specific changes are:

Line 89 (what elements to apply the CSS animate class) :

```
this.items = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.grid_4' ) );
```

Previously:

```
this.items = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#' + this.el.id + ' > li' ) );
```

Line: 100 (initializing Masonry) - Here we hardcode the class name (`.grid_4`):

```
itemSelector: '.grid_4',
```

Previously:

```
itemSelector: 'li'
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I have been struggling to figure this out for weeks.  Thank you for taking the time to break things down and explain to me each piece.  I really appreciate it.  Everything makes sense.

Comment: For some reason it still is not working, I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" in imagesloaded.js even though I am importing it as you did.  My code is the exact same as your codepen.  The only difference is I have a js file containing the javascript in the right pane of codepen.  I am importing this js file at the top of my html (also tried it on the bottom).

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia - Could you share a link (either codepen or the site) and I could take a look!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644219/why-is-this-animonscroll-js-example-working-on-codepen-but-not-on-my-local-machi

Comment: Hey Jack, if I'm trying to replicate your codepen example on my local machine, is there anything I need to change in the code to get it working?  I put the javascript from codepen (in the right pane) into it's own js file and imported it, other than that, the code is identical to your codepen example.

Comment: Hey Jack, I'm still trying to get this darn thing working.  In the codepen example you posted, I noticed you are importing ImagesLoaded.js and Masonry.js twice.  In the left pane and in the right pane.  Are these both necessary?  Can I get rid of one or the other?  Just trying to eliminate all possible causes of why this is not working

Comment: One is imported from Cloudflare, the other is imported from tympanus.